# Showing information of portfolio items and displaying several categories with MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Thank you for reading this and trying to help!

The problem I have is the following: I'm trying to create a portfolio page that displays every portfolio item using a quicksand library to sort the results on screen by categories. The tricky part is that some items can belong to more than one category.

So far what I have is this:

MySQL Tables:

**portfolio**

id | date_added | date_project | project_title | description | url | skills_used

**categories**

id | category_name

**portfolio_categories**

project_id | category_id

With this 3 tables I have been trying unsuccessfully to display the information using an INNER JOIN but I can't come up with the right query structure for this.

I basically want to display (echo) all the information in the table **portfolio** PLUS all the categories that every portfolio item is included in.

PLEASE if anyone can help me figure out the right query for this I would really appreciate it!

Thank you very much beforehand.

Comment: is portfolio to categories is one to one relation or one to many ?

Comment: also in portfolio_categories is project_id = id (portfolio) ?

Comment: Sorry I missed that before.. yes. is one to many (one portfolio item to many categories. Also, portfolio.id = portfolio_categories.project_id

Answer (score 0):

This type of question probably duplicated many times over....

```
SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.category_name SEPARATOR ',')
FROM portfolio
    LEFT JOIN portfolio_categories pc ON pc.project_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id = pc.category_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help and sorry for the inconvenience. As with the other answer, I will try this out and come back as soon as I try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Check this query:

```
"SELECT * FROM portfolio, portfolio_categories, categories  
WHERE portfolio.id = portfolio_categories.project_id 
AND portfolio_categories.category_id = categories.id";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will give this a go and come back to let you know if it has worked for me!

Comment: Hey, I have tried this option you have offered above, and yes, in a way it works. But I'm getting as many repeated project listings as categories they are listed in: example... Project 1, category 1 + Project 1, category 2 + Project 1, category 3... and what I want to achieve is: Project 1, category 1 + category 2 + category 3 (in  single iteration or listing). Please do you have a suggestion to achieve this? I have spent the last couple of days trying without success :(